# XSD: Specifying a name for a text node property

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd, xjc

I am using an XML schema and xjc to generate java classes.  I would like to define an XML structure that looks like this:

```
<unicorn color="white" superpower="transmogrification">Sparklemallow</unicorn>
```

Specifically, it has attributes, and a text node.  I can define it like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="unicorn">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
      <xs:attribute name="color" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:attribute name="superpower" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

When I generate a Java class, the property represented by the text node is called `value` by default:

```
public class Unicorn implements Serializable
{
    protected String value; //want to rename this
    protected String color;
    protected String superpower;

    ...

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public boolean isSetValue() {
        return (this.value!= null);
    }
}
```

I want to rename the text node property to something more semantically appropriate -- in this case, `name`.  Is there a way to specify what the name of this property should be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to change the name of this property by adding an annotation underneath the xs:complexType node:

```
<xs:complexType name="unicorn">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <jaxb:property name="name"/> <!-- your property name here -->
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
      <xs:attribute name="color" type="xs:ID"/>
      <xs:attribute name="superpower" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: +1 - You can also put that information in an external binding file and reference it with the `-b` flag of the XJC tool instead of putting it in the XML schema as an annotation.